# Is this equation exactly solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I would like to know, if the following equation (which resembles the Sturm-Liouville equation) is exactly solvable (and how, if yes):
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x)\frac{d}{dx}y(x)\right] - k^2p(x)y(x) = 0.$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean with "exactly solvable"? Probably a finitely expressible solution in known functions and solutions of named standard ODE? What are the assumptions on $p$, if it has roots the equation becomes singular.

Comment: @LutzLehmann $p(x)$ is and arbitrary function. So the question is whether the solution can be expressed in quadratures, and under which conditions it can be done? - please let me know, if this sounds as a better formulation.

Comment: I strongly doubt it. Already for powers or exponentials you should get something equivalent to Bessel equations or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a series of quadratures.
$$
            \frac{d}{dx}\left[p(x)\frac{d}{dx}y(x)\right] = k^2 p(x)y(x) \\
            p(x)\frac{d}{dx}y(x) = \int_0^x k^2p(x')y(x')dx'+A \\
           \frac{d}{dx}y(x) = \frac{1}{p(x)}\int_0^xk^2 p(x')y(x')dx'+A\frac{1}{p(x)} \\
        y(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{p(x'')}\int_{0}^{x''}k^2p(x')y(x')dx'dx''+A\int_0^{x}\frac{1}{p(x')}dx'+B
$$
You can start with $y=0$ and begin the process of iterating and end up with a series solution with arbitrary constants $A,B$.